# 400 error when filtering results with Graph API

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

Given these URLs:

```
const urls = {
    demos: GRAPH_ENDPOINT + `sites/${ids.siteMain}/lists/${ids.listDemos}/items?expand=fields`,
    demosScheduled: GRAPH_ENDPOINT + `sites/${ids.siteMain}/lists/${ids.listDemos}/items?expand=fields&$filter=fields/isScheduled eq 1`,
}
```

The first one works fine. It lists all entries in the sharepoint list.  The second one, however, returns a `400 (Bad Request)` error. In the debug console, it looks like this:

> /items?expand=fields&$filter=fields/isScheduled%20eq%20%271%27

I have tried it with and without quotes (`'`). It works both ways in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), and only returns the expected results. As a matter of fact, if I copy the full URL from the debug console and paste it in graph explorer, it works even with HTML encoding.

Relevant Code:

```
function callMSGraph(endpoint, token, callback) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = `Bearer ${token}`;

    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    };

    fetch(endpoint, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => callback(response, endpoint))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

function getDemos() {
    getTokenPopup(tokenRequest)
        .then(response => {
            //this does not work
            callMSGraph(urls.demosScheduled, response.accessToken, ui.displayDemos);
            //this does work
            callMSGraph(urls.demos, response.accessToken, ui.displayDemos);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try using the [JavaScript SDKs](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript) , and use the below query to run the same

```
let items = await client.api('/sites/root/lists/list_id/items?expand=fields&$filter=fields/Title+eq+\'Help+request\'')
    .header('Prefer','HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly')
    .filter('fields/isScheduled eq \1 ')
    .get();
```